# Why inputAccessoryView is not visible in visual debugging?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, inputaccessoryview

I attached here the simulator screenshot and the view debugging window.
[screenshot from xcode view debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YizJ9.png) and 
[simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6WeJ.png)

As you can see inputAccessoryView is visible in simulator but not in the visual debugging and don't understand why, please help :)

The code for the inputAccessoryView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        let v = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "inputAccessoryView"
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        return v
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`inputAccessoryView` is on another window called `UITextEffectsWindow` and for it to show up in the view debugger you have to select that window or any sub item in the window from the debug navigator tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot !